# Building ReactJS Project with Webpack causes graceful-js to report error "can't resolve 'fs'"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I was building my project last night.  It's a Node project building React distributable frontend code with webpack.  When I was done, I shut down my computer.  I turned on my computer this morning and now, with no code or config changes to my knowledge, I get errors that some kind of dependency of a dependency is missing.

```
ERROR in ./~/fsevents/~/graceful-fs/fs.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/stevenkitzes/Documents/Career Dev/C2 to A1/react-lnl/demo/react-lnl/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/graceful-fs'
 @ ./~/fsevents/~/graceful-fs/fs.js 3:9-22
 @ ./~/fsevents/~/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js
 @ ./~/fsevents/~/fstream/lib/reader.js
 @ ./~/fsevents/~/fstream/fstream.js
 @ ./~/fsevents/~/tar-pack/index.js
 @ ./~/fsevents/~/node-pre-gyp/lib/package.js
 @ ./~/fsevents/~/node-pre-gyp/lib ^\.\/.*$
 @ ./~/fsevents/~/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js
 @ ./~/fsevents/fsevents.js
 @ ./~/chokidar/lib/fsevents-handler.js
 @ ./~/chokidar/index.js
 @ ./~/watchpack/lib/DirectoryWatcher.js
 @ ./~/watchpack/lib/watcherManager.js
 @ ./~/watchpack/lib/watchpack.js
 @ (webpack)/lib/node/NodeWatchFileSystem.js
 @ (webpack)/lib ^.*$
 @ (webpack)/lib/webpack.js
 @ ./jsx-map/jsx-build.js
```

Here is my webpack config file:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, '.');

var plugins = [];

var config = {
  entry: APP_DIR + '/jsx.js',
  output: {
    path: APP_DIR,
    filename: 'jsx-out.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: APP_DIR,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: plugins
};

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: `fs` is a node built-in module. Can you try to run `node -e "require('fs')"`, if that errors you probably have a problem with the Node installation and you need to re-install it.

Comment: No error, and no problems in my other Node projects.  That's why I'm so confused!  :(

Comment: Maybe try deleting `node_modules` and reinstalling with `npm install`.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to include a build script in your app. You can't bundle files that require node built-ins (at least for the browser, the default target of webpack). Did you mean to include `./jsx-map/jsx-build.js`? If so, what is its content?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be trying to bundle both server-side (node) and client-side (react stuff) with webpack. If so you need to bundle them separately to create 2 different bundle files.

- One for node for your to exeucte e.g., `node bundle-server.js` (assuming your server-side bundle is generated as 'bundle-server.js')
- Another for inclusion into your front-end html code, e.g., `<script src='./bundle-client.js'></script>` (assuming your client-side bundle is generated as 'bundle-client.js').

Specifically you need to set options in your webpack config file to have  two 'output' and two 'target', one for server-side, and another for client-side.

For details on doing client-side and server-side bundling with webpack, you can refer to https://medium.com/code-oil/webpack-javascript-bundling-for-both-front-end-and-back-end-b95f1b429810